# JNLP: Loading unsigned code within signed code

Tags: java, classloader, code-signing, jnlp

We're having difficulties getting past the mixed code error for Java webstart. In summary, we have our main JNLP file, we've signed all of our code that it loads directly. We've added the all-permissions option to the main JNLP. The main class it loads also comes from a signed jar.

When the main class kicks off a little down the road it fires off some things that need to load some unsigned resources that are pulled in from JNLP B. None of JNLP B's resources are signed and they do not need any special permissions.

All of the signed code has been setup based on the mixed code documentation from Oracle and the jar files have been set with manifests of "Trusted-Library: true" before signing.

When the unsigned code is attempted to be loaded by the signed code we get a class not found error like so:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/some/external/package/that/is/not/signed
at org.our.signed.package.main(Main.java:87)
... 9 more

    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.some.external.package.that.is.not.signed
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 10 more
```

Here's the scenario in the JNLP's:

JNLP A: (summarized)

```
<jnlp spec="1.5+" codebase="...." href="......">
  <information>
   ...etc
  </information>
   <security>
     <all-permissions/>
   </security>
   <resources>
      <j2se version="1.6+" initial-heap-size="80m" max-heap-size="256m" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
      <jar href="signedJar_1.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
      <jar href="signedJar_2.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
      <extension name="unsigned_ext" href="unsigned.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="(FROM SIGNED CLASS in signedJar_1.jar)"/>
</jnlp>
```

JNLP B (the unsigned.jnlp loader)

```
<jnlp spec="1.5+" codebase="....." href="......">
  <information>
   ...etc
  </information>
  <resources>
    <jar href="unsigned.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <component-desc/>
</jnlp>
```

We have noted that the security exceptions are working correctly, because if we move the unsigned jar into the the JNLP that has all-permissions and has signed jars, we get the expected security exceptions that Java won't let us mix the signed code with Trusted-Library: true and unsigned code with no manifest attributes.

Ideas? Is there a reason the classloader can't find the java files from the unsigned code? Is there something special we are missing to allow signed code to run unsigned code? I've only seen the cases where people have problems getting unsigned code to run signed code, which I can understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trusted-library class loader is a parent (in the sense of class loader delegation) of the (possibly untrusted) applet class loader. Think of it as if it is the boot class loader. So the untrusted classes can link to the trusted-library classes but not vice versa. Without going to the bother of altering manifests and using WebStart you can try this stuff out by adding your trusted class with `-Xbootclasspath/a:` and your untrusted classes with `-classpath` (this is how the feature was tried out before it was implemented).

`JNLPAppletLauncher` is an example of how to have trusted-libraries invoke applet code. The applet class loader can be obtained with `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`, and it's just reflection from there. Writing safe trusted library code is tricky. Remember, you can't trust untrusted code.

Comment: So you're saying that trusted code can't run untrusted code at all? For example, our app is an in-house CRM that loads via web start (no applets). Our CRM sometimes needs access to the local file system (the reason for signing / all-perm). Our CRM also needs some other jars though for other things - such as swingx.jar for the UI, help sets such as jhall.jar, etc. So then our trusted code can't get access to these other jars? Would we have to pull out our trusted functions into their own jars and sign only those and let our main core be untrusted so we could also use untrusted jars?

Comment: (Applet and JNLPWebStart application/applet are essentially interchangeable.) You can't have trusted code relying upon the behaviour of untrusted code. You can have trusted code as a library, but you need to be very careful that any operation at all performed on it is safe. You can't just have a method which, say, saves some data to a specified file name (and remains secure).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline If the code in the sand-boxed extension was digitally signed, would it still cause a problem?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Do you mean if you have a trusted-library with a trusted applet/application? From a class loading perspective, that will behave the same as a trusted-library with untrusted applet/application. Also if trusted but didn't have `<all-permissions/>`. / Note, you only really need reflection to access the first constructor/method/field. If that gives an object of a class that extends a type in the trusted-library (or Java library), then further interaction can be done through that.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I tried moving our main loader to an unsigned code, removed the all perms from the main jnlp, and moved out all the trusted code into it's own jars, with their own jnlp's and signed those. We still got errors saying that our signed code being executed from the jnlp with the all-perms was not authorized. To solve our issue, we have reverted to the last suggestion on Oracle's website of signing everything, and then our jar's that are third party are in jnlp's that do not have the all-permissions security model. It loads without error now, but probably not ideal.

Comment: *"Do you mean if you have a trusted-library.."* Aach! The `trusted-library` had completely slipped my mind.